# Postman Test for Api that immediately returns SUCCESS response

Tags: aws-lambda, postman, postman-testcase

I have an Api (in AWS) which immediately returns a "SUCCESS" response after a call is made (in a lambda) but I'd like to test the output of a subsequent step.
First lambda places data on a SQS queue which is retrieved by another lambda who's output I'd like to test/verify).

Is this possible using Postman?

**Example:**

User: Send json data to Api Gateway Endpoint (POST call) which in turn is handled by Lambda 1

Lambda 1: parse json payload, perform some validation, place payload on queue (SQS), and return unique token to caller indicating SUCCESS

Lambda 2: Process message from SQS and send json message to external endpoint

Postman Testing: Can test sending of message and SUCCESS response but how could the json payload sent to the external endpoint be tested? How could Postman access this to validate?

Possible Solution: Store the payload in the Database and provide a REST endpoint to allow Postman to access it with the token returned in first step. Postman to poll until message available.

Comment: Please give us a concrete example

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Unless that first request is returning you some sort of id or something that you can use in a sub-sequent request i don't see how you would verify anything. Also if that 2nd endpoint isn't accessible or it does not have an endpoint you can hit I don't think there's a way for you to verify anything.